# Finding those employees who had joined in 1st quarter of the year

Tags: mysql

Finding record of those employees who had joined in 1st quarter of the year,I have tried the following query but I want the query without specifying the explicit date.

```
select * from employee where DOJ between '2015-01-01' and '2015-03-31';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [quarter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter)

```
select * from employee where year(DOJ) = 2015 and quarter(DOJ) = 1;
```